# insert values to databases from R:Error in sqlQuery(con, req) : first argument is not an open RODBC channel

Tags: sql, r, insert, insert-into

queries a postgresql database:

code:

```
drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
con <- dbConnect(drv, dbname="BDDMeteo", user=user, password="zina",host='localhost', port='5432')
#selection
cluster1=dbGetQuery(con,"select station.lon,station.lat from station where station.cluster=1")  
#insertion
req=paste("INSERT INTO important (num_cluster,type,indicateur_imp) VALUES (1,'temperature',2)")
resultat=sqlQuery(con,req)
```

for how to select good, but for the insertion he sends me the following error:

```
Error in sqlQuery(con, req) : first argument is not an open RODBC channel
```

help please?

Comment: `VALUES (1,'temperature','Imp1'))"`

Answer (score 1):

You missed brackets after `VALUES Clause`

```
req=paste("INSERT INTO Important (Num_cluster,Type,Indicateur_impt) VALUES (1,'temperature','Imp1')")
resultat=sqlQuery(con,req)
```

Comment: still the same error
the fact my Id is serial type, that is not worth mentioning?
Num_cluster: integer
Type: Character
indicateur_impt: real

Comment: your id is auto-increment?

Comment: try to run only insert query directly in database INSERT INTO Important (Num_cluster,Type,Indicateur_impt) VALUES (1,'temperature','Imp1')

Comment: yes work in direct sql query postgresql databases, but doesn't work from R

Comment: > req=paste("INSERT INTO important (num_cluster,type,indicateur_imp) VALUES (1,'temperature',2)")
> resultat=sqlQuery(con,req)
Error in sqlQuery(con, req) : first argument is not an open RODBC channel
>

Comment: @user26480 The error is consistently telling you that `con` is not an open RODBC channel. You should be investigating that, not the query itself. The query isn't even making it to the db. Edit your question to show the code you used to open the connection.